# nextjs 14 (app router) how to add some file to the root?

Tags: next.js

I have nextjs version 14 application, and I need to add some file to the root;

for example "simple.txt", if I place it to the "app" directory ("app/simple.txt") it's ignoring it.

The same result if I place it to pulic directory.

I wanna see result in browser when I go to "http://example.com/simple.txt" just text from that file

Answer (score 0):

downgrading sharp library fix the issue

Comment: Just a suggestion for future answers, might be good to capture details on the specifics of the downgrade, e.g. "I downgraded from version X to version Y"